# MySQL inner join, check from different table

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables formatted as below:

```
INSERT INTO `mixture` (`id`, `item`) VALUES
(1,'water'),
(2,'gas'),
(3,'oil'),
(4,'ice');
```

**another table**

```
INSERT INTO `check` (`name`, `seen`) VALUES
('Nadia','[2][3]'),
('Omer','[1][4][2]');
```

**result needed:**
How do I get the result to show this?
Nadia will only see information that has mixture.id 1 & 4, while
Omer will only see information that has mixture.id 3

Each time they see the result, mixture.id will be added to their check.seen status, so that they will not see the same information in the future.

This is what I have done so far:

```
SELECT
    mixture.*,
    check.seen,
    check.name
FROM mixture
INNER JOIN check
WHERE check.seen not like '%[mixture.id]%'
```

Thanks in advance
Please make my day.

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: This has nothing to do with phpmyadmin, it has something to do with sql and you have not said what question you are asking, what do you want? and please show your work you have done already.

Comment: Please edit this question, so you can get answers. With the question at hand, there's nothing to answer.

Comment: 1. See normalization.

Answer (score 0):

The index should be a numeric type like a integer not a string, no quotes around the numbers

Your another table will have a row for each mixture known by the person

('Nadia',2)
('Nadia',3)
('Omer',1)
('Omer',4)
('Omer',2)

A select for Nadia will return a record set with 2 records, one for each mixture she knows, 3 for Omer

```
Select seen FROM anothertable where name = 'Nadia'
```

a join will return the correct mixture item string from your first table.

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp